# Keep a global <View> always over all pages

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'am creating a pages navigation using `react-navigation` dependency as thé example below :

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }
});
const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

I would like to create one global `View` that still always shown over `HomeScreen` and `ProfileScreen` pages.

Comment: are you asking about the header or something like that?

Comment: it's about any kind of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }
});

class MainNavigatorWithCustomView extends React.Component {
  static router = MainNavigator.router;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <MainNavigator {...this.props} />
        {/* render some absolute positioned thing on top here */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```